# Python program: a tool to convert binary numbers to decimal, and decimal numbers to binary, and a simple text-only menu to add or subtract numbers

Tags: python

Python program: a tool to convert binary numbers to decimal, and decimal numbers to binary, and a simple text-only menu to add or subtract numbers.

To the creator could you please adjust the code so it looks like the code you have in your editor? I cannot read this.

```
 import sys
```

Binary To Decimal

```
def bintodec(binnum):
     l = len(binnum)
     s = binnum
     dec = 0
     for i in range(0,l):
         b = s[l-i-1]
         dec = dec + int(b)*(2**i)
         return dec
```

Decimal To Binary

```
 def dectobin(decnum):
     if decnum==0:
         return "00000000"
     bin=""
     while decnum>0:
         bin = str(decnum%2) + bin
         decnum = decnum/2

     if len(bin)%8 != 0:
         n = 8*(len(bin)/8 + 1) - len(bin)
         bin = "0" + bin
         return bin

 def show_menu():
     print ("What do you want to do?")
     print ("1. Enter the first number")
     print ("2. Enter the second number")
     print ("3. Add the two numbers together")
     print ("4. Subtract the second number from the first")
     print ("5. Exit the program\n")
     show_menu()
      inp = input() 
      n1 = "" 
      n2 = "" 
      while inp !=5:
     if inp=="1":
         n1 = str(input("Enter the first number\n"))
         print ("The first number chosen is: " + str(n1) + "\n")
         show_menu()
     if inp=="2":
         n2= str(input("Enter the second number\n"))
         print ("The first number chosen is: " + str(n1))
         print ("The second number chosen is: " + str(n2) +"\n")
         show_menu()
     if inp=="3":
         print ("The sum of the two numbers is: " + dectobin(bintodec(n1) + bintodec(n2)) + "\n")
     exit()
     if inp=="4":
         if bintodec(n2)<bintodec(n1):
             print ("For this selection second number should be greater than or equal to first")
         else:
             print ("The difference beween the two numbers is: " + dectobin(bintodec(n2) - bintodec(n1)) + "\n")
         exit()
     inp = input()
```

Comment: Sorry I was having a problem editing the code on here, my problem is when ever I run the code and enter my input my numbers such as 1 + 1 it gives me a huge string of numbers

Comment: Remove all the > at the start of each line. Then select the code and hit ctrl-k.

Comment: Ok, so you have some code to do something, what's the question?  (ie: What's the problem with your code that you are experiencing?)

Comment: When ever I run the code it and enter my first and second number and add them together it gives me a huge string of numbers as my answer when all i do is try to add 1 + 1 together

Comment: heres a link for repl.it just in case the edits on here aren't right
https://repl.it/repls/EvergreenPlainAmericanlobster

Comment: Please edit your post to describe what exactly your issue is; do not use the comments for this, except for (very) minor clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there you go :P Decided to use a switch object because it was interesting. However i'm finding it tough to exit the switch with input '5'

```
class switch(object):
    value = None
    def __new__(class_, value):
        class_.value = value
        return True

def case(*args):
    return any((arg == switch.value for arg in args))

def bintodec(binnum):
    return int(str(binnum), 2)

def add(first, second):
    try:
        first = int(first,2)
        second = int(second,2)
    except:
        pass
    print('result')
    print(int(first) + int(second))
    print('')

def sub(first, second):
    try:
        first = int(first,2)
        second = int(second,2)
    except:
        pass    
    print('result')
    print(int(second) - int(first))
    print('')


def show_menu():

    while True:
        print ("What do you want to do?")
        print ("1. Enter the first number")
        print ("2. Enter the second number")
        print ("3. Add the two numbers together")
        print ("4. Subtract the second number from the first")
        print ("5. Exit the program\n")            
        ask_for_input = input('Enter Switch\n')
        ask_for_input = int(ask_for_input)

        while switch(ask_for_input):
            if case(1):
                ask_for_1_num = input("Enter the first number\n")
                break
            if case(2):
                ask_for_2_num = input("Enter the second number\n")
                break
            if case(3):
                add(ask_for_1_num, ask_for_2_num)
                break
            if case(4):
                sub(ask_for_1_num, ask_for_2_num)
                break
            if case(5):
                break
            break    

def main():
    show_menu()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hopefully this is solved now? Might need some work in some places, i'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you so much, been a big help

Comment: What in the world is this switch stuff. Why not just use if/elif statements?

Comment: You can if you want, won't be hard to change it, i know its not exactly pythonic, just wanted to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Through much confusion as to what you were trying to do this is what i could come up with:

```
# Binary To Decimal
def bintodec(binnum):
    return int(str(binnum), 2)

#Decimal To Binary   
def dectobin(x):
    return int(bin(x)[2:])

def ask_for_numbers():
    number_list = 0
    while True:
        ask_for_operand = input('Would you like to add or sub')
        ask_for_number = input('Please enter a number: ')
        try:
            if ask_for_operand == 'add':
                try:
                    number_list += bintodec(ask_for_number)
                except:
                    number_list += int(ask_for_number)
                print(number_list)
            elif ask_for_operand == 'sub':
                try:
                    number_list -= bintodec(ask_for_number)
                except:
                    number_list -= int(ask_for_number)
                print(number_list)
            else:
                return number_list
        except ValueError:
            print("Not Int or Bin")

def main():
    print(ask_for_numbers())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Clearly I had to start again, the decimal to binary function was not needed. The issue with doing it this way is that if i want to add the decimal '10' the function ask_for_numbers() will want to convert that into a binary value. Maybe you can edit this code to figure it out.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: awesome I appreciate it, sadly I have to have the full menu in there like I have it though and it has to ask for both numbers like it is, just wish I could figure out why I get that huge string of numbers when I add or subtract